# Useless Spreadsheet Export - PowerShell (O365) - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to run a report from Office 365 in a hybrid environment where I can grab some properties about every mailbox in the system and export it to a spreadsheet for management's review. I have tried a number of variations of below command, but none seem to output meaningful spreadsheet data, I just get a line count equal to my mailboxes and a bunch of strings in column 1, then nothing else really.

I am connect to office365 via a PS session.

Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here or if there is a better way of achieving the desired results and creating this report?

Thanks!

```
Get-Mailbox -resultsize unlimited | Format-Table -AutoSize | Export-Csv -Path c:\Users\myusername\Desktop\magicreport.csv | Select-Object name,@{n="UPN";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -UserPrincipalName $_.identity)}},@{n="Display Name";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -DisplayName $_.identity)}},@{n="Primary Size";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics $_.identity).totalItemsize}},@{n="Archive Size";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -archive $_.identity).TotalItemSize}},@{n="Auto Expanding Archive";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -AutoExpandingMailboxEnabled $_.identity)}},@{n="Retention Policy";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -RetentionPolicy $_.identity)}},@{n="Litigation Hold";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -LitigationHoldEnabled $_.identity)}},@{n="Shared";e={(Get-MailboxStatistics -IsShared $_.identity)}}
```

Comment: please add to your Question the output you are getting.

Comment: you have used `Format-Table` for something other than FINAL output ... and that will give you garbage [text formatting layout code]. try removing that. [*grin*]

Comment: Lee_Dailey is right. Remove the `Format-Table`. `Format-*` cmdlets should only be used at the right side of your scripts. When you're exporting to CSV or wish to use the data for any further processing, do not use it at all.